# Proper way of dealing with input prompts in Capistrano?

Tags: shell, automation, capistrano, apt-get

What is the correct way of dealing with input prompts that are triggered by commands I run through Capistrano?

One example is the `iptables-persistent` package I install using `aptitude`. Despite the `--no-gui` flag, a prompt still comes up asking me to confirm how I want things configured.

Is there a way to pass parameters through command line to avoid such prompts?

Answer (score 0):

I found and was able to implement this very helpful handle_command_with_input method from:

https://github.com/nesquena/cap-recipes/blob/master/lib/cap_recipes/tasks/utilities.rb

```
def handle_command_with_input(local_run_method, shell_command, input_query, response=nil)
send(local_run_method, shell_command, {:pty => true}) do |channel, stream, data|
  if data =~ input_query
    if response
      logger.info "#{data} #{"*"*(rand(10)+5)}", channel[:host]
      channel.send_data "#{response}\n"
    else
      logger.info data, channel[:host]
      response = ::Capistrano::CLI.password_prompt "#{data}"
      channel.send_data "#{response}\n"
    end
  else
    logger.info data, channel[:host]
  end
end
end
```

None of the code is mine.  Gracias a Nesquena.